# Проблема с командной строкой

Tags: python, pip

Всем добрый день. Возникла проблема с командной строкой. Переустановил и пайтон и Wing, при запуске программы винг пишет:

```
builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'
```

Без проблем, хочу установить

```
pip install pillow
```

на что вылезает ошибка в самой командной строке:

```
C:\Users\iljal>pip install pillow
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\iljal\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\iljal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\pip.exe" install pillow': ?? ??????? ????? ????????? ????.
```

командная строка вообще ведет себя странно. Подскажите как решить проблему? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Данная ошибка возникает всегда, если хочу установить какую-нибудь библиотеку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переустановить pip

В командной строке:

`cd C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32` (путь до питона)

```
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
python.exe -m easy_install pip
```

- переустановка pip

```
cd Scripts
pip install pillow
```

И установка pillow

Также эта ошибка может возникать из-за пробелов в пути до файла

Похожие вопросы:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24627525/fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using-c-program-files-x86
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37220055/pip-fatal-error-in-launcher-unable-to-create-process-using